# check if a Firebase App is already initialized in python

Tags: python, firebase

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.

How Can I check if the default firebase app is already initialized or not in python?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 81):

The best way is to control your app workflow so the initialization is called only once. But of course, idempotent code is also a good thing, so here is what you can do to avoid that error:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json') 
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this earlier, but on app engine after few trials again I get the same error

Comment: I followed the above syntax and got :
 if (!firebase_admin.apps.length):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah, I used `!` instead of `not`, javascript kiddie here... edited my answer

Comment: being pythonic: if not firebase_admin._apps:

Answer (score 10):

Initialize the app in the constructor

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

then in your method you call

```
firebase_admin.get_app()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin

Comment: I wanted to do something like this "if not firebase_admin.get_app():", but I only get an error "The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app()." even when checking the type or when printing it.

Answer (score 9):

I use this try / except block to handle initialisation of the app

```
try:
    app = firebase_admin.get_app()
except ValueError as e:
    cred = credentials.Certificate(CREDENTIALS_FIREBASE_PATH)
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Comment: Using an exception for execution flow is never the right answer.  The app being initialised a second time is a bug, not and exception.

Answer (score 8):

I've found the following to work for me.

For the default app:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

if firebase_admin._DEFAULT_APP_NAME in firebase_admin._apps:
    # do something.
```

I have been using it in this way with a named app:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

if 'my_app_name' not in firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')        
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
            'databaseURL': 'https://{}.firebaseio.com'.format(project_id),
            'storageBucket': '{}.appspot.com'.format(project_id)}, name='my_app_name')
```

Comment: This is the only code that working for me for checking fierbase app already exists! Great thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you ended up here due to building Cloud Functions in GCP with Python that interacts with Firestore, then this is what worked for me:

The reason for using an exception for control flow here is that the **firebase_admin._apps** is a protected member of the module, so accessing it directly is not best practice either.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore


def init_with_service_account(file_path):
     """
     Initialize the Firestore DB client using a service account
     :param file_path: path to service account
     :return: firestore
     """
     cred = credentials.Certificate(file_path)
     try:
         firebase_admin.get_app()
     except ValueError:
         firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
     return firestore.client()


def init_with_project_id(project_id):
    """
    Initialize the Firestore DB client using a GCP project ID
    :param project_id: The GCP project ID
    :return: firestore
    """
    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    try:
        firebase_admin.get_app()
    except ValueError:
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    return firestore.client()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I prefer this answer.  I know the dude above said we shouldn't handle exceptions as part of the logic workflow but it's Google's fault for not providing a better option than accessing a protected member.  At least this way, PyCharm isn't screaming at me for it.  To each its own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
firebase_admin.delete_app(firebase_admin.get_app())
```

And execute the code again

Answer (score 1):

You can also use default credentials

```
 if (not len(firebase_admin._apps)):
    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'projectId': "yourprojetid"})
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I faced a similar error. But my issue was, I have initialized the app twice in my python file. So it crashed my whole python file and returns a
`ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.` 
I solved this by removing one of my firebase app initialization. I hope this will help someone!!

Answer (score 0):

**Reinitializing more than one app in firebase using python**:

You need to give different name for different app

For every app we will be generating one object store those objects in list and access those object one by one later

```
def getprojectid(proj_url):
    p = r'//(.*)\.firebaseio'
    x = re.findall(p, url)
    return x[0]

objects = []
count = 0
details = dict()

def addtofirebase(json_path, url):
    global objects, count, details
    my_app_name = getprojectid(url) # Function which returns project ID
    if my_app_name not in firebase_admin._apps: 
            cred = credentials.Certificate(json_path)        
            obj = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,xyz , name=my_app_name) # create the object
            objects.append(obj) # Store Initialized Objects in one list
            details[my_app_name] = count # Storing index of object in dictionary to access it later using project id 
            count += 1
            ref = db.reference('/',app= objects[details[my_app_name])  # using this reference, change database

        else:
            ref = db.reference('/',app= objects[details[my_app_name])  # from next time it will get update here. it will not get initialise again and again
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the the app global, don't put the initialize_app() inside the function because whenever the function called it also calls the initialize_app() again.

```
CRED = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json') 
DEFAULT_APP = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def function():
    """call default_app and process data here"""
```

Comment: this is wrong. on the server the app run for each call anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use don't need key.json file. You can default gcloud credentials to authenticate.

```
gcloud auth application-default login --project="yourproject"
```

python code:

```
import firebase_admin

app_options = {'projectId': 'yourproject'}
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(options=app_options)
```